# How to drag Custom Usercontrol on windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, user-controls

I have a sln file with two projects in it, the first project contains a Custom Usercontrol inherited from Button, the second project has a form and a button on it, when i click the button on the form the Custom Usercontrol which is a button will be added to the form, now i should be able to drag the button on the form wherever i want to on the form after i run it, how to do it.

```
public partial class buttCustom : Button
{
    public buttCustom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(buttControl);
    }
}
```

[image]

i should be able to move that green custom button in the image to move anywhere i want using mouse.

Comment: Override the `MouseMove`/`MouseDown`/`MouseUp` events and move the item when the mouse is down and moving over the button. There are a lot of tutorials online about how to drag controls around on a form.

Comment: i know but how drag a control that is added when i click the button ? for example i will add multiple controls to the form by clicking the button then how to move them ?

Comment: Its the same logic for one as it is for 100.

Comment: how to identify that particular button when my mouse is on it ? is there any method ?

Comment: Yes, handle the mouse events *of the button*. The "sender" object is actually the button, and you can cast it to a `buttCustom` object and modify any properties it has (like `Top` and `Left` or `Location`)

Comment: A working example can be found here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the code below in your custom User Control class.

```
[DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
[DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr one, int two, int three, int four);

private void CustomCtrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ReleaseCapture();
    SendMessage(Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
}
```

So the result would be something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyViewer.CustomControls
{

    public partial class CustomCtrl : UserControl
    {
        public string formTitleText
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }
        public CustomCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
        private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr one, int two, int three, int four);


        // Add MouseDown Event
        private void CustomCtrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can add the custom User Control which can be draggable to your form from the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Agula Otgonbaatar has the correct answer, however I use these values

```
public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;
```

I also check for MouseButton.Left in my MouseDown handler, so it would be:

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    ReleaseCapture();
    SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
}
```

This works for me.